# Express Middleware flow

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Consider the following Express app:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('\n\nALWAYS')
  next()
})

app.get('/a', (req, res) => {
  console.log('/a: route terminated')
  res.send('/a')
})

app.use((req, res) => {
  console.log('route not handled')
  res.send('404 - not found')
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on 3000')
})
```

Visit `/a` console result:

```
ALWAYS
/a: route terminated


ALWAYS
route not handled
```

Can somebody explain why is that there is another middleware log? I was expecting only 2 lines of console log. Instead

```
ALWAYS
route not handled
```

has been logged.

Comment: Use ```curl``` or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps). Your browser sends 2 requests. 1 for the route and 1 for ```/favicon.ico```. If you log the request you'll set it's a separate request

Comment: It's useful for debugging to log something like `console.log("req", req.originalUrl)` or similar so you're not working blind.

Comment: Many thanks @Wainage! How could I not notice that! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common point of confusion.  The likely cause is that you went to `/a` in the browser and the browser made two requests.  One for `/favicon.ico` and one for `/a` (that's what browsers do when you go to a new site they haven't previously cached the favicon for - the little glyph they display that represents the web site in some places in the browser).

If you log the request URL in your middleware and in your 404 handler, you will see the details of what is happening:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.use((req, res, next) => {

  console.log('\n\nRequest for: ', req.url);
  next();
})

app.get('/a', (req, res) => {
  console.log('/a: route terminated')
  res.send('/a')
})

app.use((req, res) => {
  console.log('route not handled for ', req.url);
  res.send('404 - not found');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on 3000')
})
```